# Chrome inline installation works only half of the time

Tags: google-chrome-extension, failed-installation, chrome-web-store

we've set up a simple inline [webstore installe](http://www.capturetocloud.com/testsupport.html)r for our app.

The app site has been verified.  The inline installation does work correctly for half of us inside our company, but it doesn't work for the other half.  They would get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'install' of undefined testsupport.html:15
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).  It's as though the chrome or chrome.web variable isn't initialized.

Why does the inline installation work only on some machines but not on others?  All these machines have the same chrome browser version.

TIA

Comment: Chiming in with an annoying "me too" here. I have the same problem of the chrome.webstore object being undefined. When I try to install your extension via the test page you posted, I always get the installation dialog. I wonder if the extension has to be publicly published? I have it published to testers, of which I am one, and I can see the CWS page with no problem. I've been trying the methods on this page but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I just wanted to note a few facts about CWS inline installation that I learned the hard way: A CWS items has to be published to the public; it can't just be published to testers. Also, after publishing, it's necessary to wait a little while before the binary propagates through Google's network. When I first pushed the publish button on my extension and then attempted rapidly clicking the install button from my site to trigger inline installation, it would trigger inline install perhaps 1 / 10 times because the extension wasn't everywhere in Google's network yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen this issue before but I will try to provide a breakdown of the setup I use to manage [inline installations](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) for the multiple Chrome extensions on [my website](http://neocotic.com).

Within the `head` node of every page (optionally, only pages that may include one or more Install links) I add the required links to each extension/app page on the Chrome Web Store. This allows me to easily add install links anywhere on the page for various extensions/apps. The JavaScript simply binds an event handler to each of the install links once the DOM has finished loading. This event handler's sole purpose is to install the extension/app that it links to when clicked and then to change its state to prevent further install attempts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <!-- Link for each extension/app page -->
    <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf">
    <script>
      // Ensure that the DOM has fully loaded
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // Support other browsers
        var chrome = window.chrome || {};
        if (chrome.app && chrome.webstore) {
          // Fetch all install links
          var links = document.querySelectorAll('.js-chrome-install');
          // Create "click" event listener
          var onClick = function(e) {
            var that = this;
            // Attempt to install the extension/app
            chrome.webstore.install(that.href, function() {
              // Change the state of the button
              that.innerHTML = 'Installed';
              that.classList.remove('js-chrome-install');
              // Prevent any further clicks from attempting an install
              that.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
            });
            // Prevent the opening of the Web Store page
            e.preventDefault();
          };
          // Bind "click" event listener to links
          for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].addEventListener('click', onClick);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <!-- Allow inline installation links to be easily identified -->
    <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf" class="js-chrome-install">Install</a>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In order for this system to work fully you also need to support scenarios where the user has returned to your website after installing your extension/app. Although the official documentation suggests using `chrome.app.isInstalled` this doesn't work when multiple extensions/apps can be installed from a single page. To get around this issue you can simply add a content script to your extension/app like the following install.js file;

```js
// Fetch all install links for this extension/app running
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.js-chrome-install[href$=dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf]');
// Change the state of all links
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].innerHTML = 'Installed';
  // Website script will no longer bind "click" event listener as this will be executed first
  links[i].classList.remove('js-chrome-install');
}
```

Then you just need to modify your manifest.json file to ensure this content script is executed on your domain.

```js
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["install.js"],
      "matches": ["*://*.yourdomain.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

This will result in the content script being run before the JavaScript on your website so there will be no install links with the `js-chrome-install` class by the time it is executed, thus no event handlers will be bound etc.

Below is an example of how I use this system;

**Homepage:** http://neocotic.com

**Project Homepage:** http://neocotic.com/template

**Project Source Code:** https://github.com/neocotic/template

Answer (score 1):

Your inline installation markup is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="chrome.webstore.install()">
  CaptureToCloud Chrome Extension Installation
</a>
```

(per one of the comments, it used `javascript:void(0)` before, which is equivalent to `#` in this case).

Your `<a>` tag both navigates the page and has an `onclick` handler. In some cases, the navigation takes place before the `onclick` handler finishes running, which disturbs the code that supports inline installation.

If you switch to using a plain `<span>` (styled to look like a like, if you'd like), then you should no longer have this problem:

```
<span onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" style="text-decoration: underline; color:blue">
  CaptureToCloud Chrome Extension Installation
</span>
```

Alternatively, you can `return false` from your `onclick` handler to prevent the navigation:

```
<a href="#" onclick="chrome.webstore.install(); return false;">
  CaptureToCloud Chrome Extension Installation
</a>
```

(though since you're not actually linking anywhere, there isn't much point in using the `<a>` tag)

Answer (score 0):

I get the error you mentioned AND a popup window that allows me to install the extension. So probably everybody get the error but for some it is preventing installation.

I got rid of the error by replacing `javascript:void()` by `#` in `href`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="chrome.webstore.install()">CaptureToCloud Chrome Extension Installation</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with that replacement I'm still getting the same result of no popup.  :^(

Comment: I added some alert() testing and found that the variable chrome is defined but not chrome.webstore.  Somehow the <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mkgjlgfgcbmbdphpekbienchiehfmmhf"> in the head element has failed to do its injection magic.  I compare the fiddler debug-tool output with that on a machine for which this page works but cannot see any difference between the two.